# Circuit resembling wheatstone bridge but not exactly

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries

[image: electric circuit]

The below circuit resembles that of two individual wheatstone bridge arrangements as the ratio of resistances satisfy the conditions however we cannot come to this conclusion as potential at one end of the bridge is not same ie., Potential at S and T may or may not be same. This circuit needs tedious calculations if one goes to kirchoff's laws. But this highly symmetric circuit gives me a feel that there is some simpler approach. Could someone help me exploit the symmetry in the circuit ?

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting question because it is difficult if you have the right tools for it and easy if you don’t. Setters use this kind of question to make sure that students don’t just learn clever techniques, but *learn to think* whether they are needed.

The “clever” way in this case would be to notice that there are triangles of resistors, remember the formula for transforming from a delta to a star configuration, apply it, and carry on from there. Necessary in the general case, but with the particular values of resistances shown here, what they are asking is not “Does she know how to apply this advanced technique?” but “Is she alert enough to notice she doesn’t need to?”

Here is an answer with no calculation at all.

1. Throw away all the resistors except the line of three at the top. Note that they are all equal so that the potential difference across the chain including P and S is divided exactly into thirds: in this particular example, 0V, 4V, 8V, 12V.
2. Throw away all the resistors except the line of three at the bottom. Note that they are all equal so that the potential difference across the chain including Q and T is divided exactly into thirds: in this particular example, 0V, 4V, 8V, 12V.
3. Put together 1 and 2. Then both lines of resistors are dividing *the same potential difference* into thirds. So the potential at P equals the potential at Q and the potential at S equals the potential at T.
4. You can put the vertical resistors in now if you like. Their value doesn’t matter because the potential at each end of each of them is identical, so no current will flow.

Comment: ''Note that they are all equal so that the potential difference across the chain including P and S is divided exactly into thirds: in this particular example, 0V, 4V, 8V, 12V'' . Thro these lines u are already concluding that there is no split of current at P and S ( cos only then potential divides equally). But my entire qn is how to come this conclusion ? Why not it is like current flow across PQ ?

Comment: @Sarah I think you're being a little too demanding. You asked for a method that exploited the symmetry. That's exactly what this answer presents, but now you seem to be ruling out the appeal to symmetry! [Even though it's presented very nicely as there being no 'waiting' pd between P and Q or between S and T.]

Answer (score 2):

The currents in PQ and ST are null.

If you're not confident in "simplifying" electrical circuits, I leave it a solution of the circuit, exploting principle of superposition. We can define a "ring" current for every loop of the circuit, and write the current in the wire as the sum of ring currents, paying attention at the directions of the currents. As an example, following the (arbitrary) directions of the drawing, currents in PQ, PS and TS read

$i_{PQ} = i_1 - i_2, \quad i_{PS} = i_2,  \quad i_{TS} = i_2 - i_3$

[image]

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. I tried attempting the qn using kirchoff's loop law however the job seems to be tedious. I wanna know if there is any way to simplify this highly symmetric circuit without using the basic laws...

Comment: I guess that the answer is experience, experience and experience again. There are some classical methods to simplify electrical circuits to get equivalent, smaller electric circuits (this change of topology must be equivalent to algebraic operations on the linear system solving the circuit): laws for parallel and series elements, Norton and Thevenin theorems, transformations triangle-star,... Answer by Martin exploits symmetry and probably he's much better than us in solving circuits, since I would not be that confident in solving my exercises like this. Too risky to get wrong results for me.

Comment: Ok thank you so much for ur help

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to  physics stack exchange

Instead of using the Wheatstone bridge, I suggest you have a look at how the current I1 is being divided at the common node(hint:-It's in such a way that the potential difference across both the 2ohm and 4ohm resistor is the same). That should help you decide which branches you can eliminate

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ''It's in such a way that the potential difference across both the 2ohm and 4ohm resistor is the same ''. What is the reasoning for the above statement ?

Comment: so basically current(as far as I know), tries to take the path of least resistance, which would mean most current flows via the 2ohm resistor. S if xA flows via the 4ohm resistor, 2x would flow via the 2 ohm resistor. so 3x=I, . You can then find the currents in terms of I1, which would tell you the PDs are the same

Comment: Please take this with a grain of salt for I' still in school.

Comment: ':xA flows via the 4ohm resistor, 2x would flow via the 2 ohm resistor''. This is true only when potential difference across both the ends of the parallel combination is same. But here it is not sure if the combination is parallel . It' s parallel only when u consider no current thro PQ , which again comes to my 1st qn ie., how to conclude no current flows thro PQ with using lengthy calculation using KLL.

Comment: ah, my bad. KVL, KCL is the way to go in that case. Sorry